# Export Selenium test case as Junit

Tags: jakarta-ee, selenium, junit4, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE (1.5.0) to make test cases, and I want to export them as Junit so that I can run them with Maven, but i can see different Junit options, and i am confused which one to choose:

1. JUnit 4 (WebDriver).
2. Junit 4 (Remote Control).
3. JUnit 4 (WebDriver Backed).

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [comparison of the trade-offs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#driver-specifics-and-tradeoffs) in the documentation.  In short, the Java version of WebDriver provides an implementation of the Selenium-RC API.  It is largely included for backward compatibility you should use pure WebDriver if you can.